# Error CS0535: 'CMTaskPriorityRepository' does not implement interface member 'ICMTaskPriorityRepository.GetAllCMTaskPriority()

Tags: c#, api, blazor

When i try to compile i keep getting the following error. Hopefully it is something simple i have missed.

Error CS0535: 'CMTaskPriorityRepository' does not implement interface member 'ICMTaskPriorityRepository.GetAllCMTaskPriority()

CMTaskPriorityRepository.cs

```
 public class CMTaskPriorityRepository : ICMTaskPriorityRepository
    {
        private readonly AppDbContext _appDbContext;

        public CMTaskPriorityRepository(AppDbContext appDbContext)
        {
            _appDbContext = appDbContext;

        }

        public IEnumerable<CMTaskPriority> GetAllCMTaskPrioritys()
        {
            return _appDbContext.CMTaskPriority;
        }

        public IEnumerable<CMTaskPriority> GetCMTaskPrioritys()
        {
            return _appDbContext.CMTaskPriority;
        }

        public CMTaskPriority GetCMTaskPriorityById(int cmtaskpriorityid)
        {
            return _appDbContext.CMTaskPriority.FirstOrDefault(c => c.TaskPriorityID == cmtaskpriorityid);
        }

        public CMTaskPriority CreateCMTaskPriority(CMTaskPriority cmtaskpriority)
        {
            var addedEntity = _appDbContext.CMTaskPriority.Add(cmtaskpriority);
            _appDbContext.SaveChanges();
            return addedEntity.Entity;
        }

        CMTaskPriority ICMTaskPriorityRepository.UpdateCMTaskPriority(CMTaskPriority cmtaskpriority)
        {
            var foundCMTaskPriority = _appDbContext.CMTaskPriority.FirstOrDefault(e => e.TaskPriorityID == cmtaskpriority.TaskPriorityID);

            if (foundCMTaskPriority != null)
            {
                foundCMTaskPriority.TaskPriorityID = cmtaskpriority.TaskPriorityID;
                foundCMTaskPriority.PriorityLevel = cmtaskpriority.PriorityLevel;
                foundCMTaskPriority.DisplayOrder = cmtaskpriority.DisplayOrder;
                foundCMTaskPriority.IsDeletd = cmtaskpriority.IsDeletd;

                _appDbContext.SaveChanges();

                return foundCMTaskPriority;
            }

            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

ICMTaskPriorityRepository.cs

```
public interface ICMTaskPriorityRepository
    {
        IEnumerable<CMTaskPriority> GetAllCMTaskPriority();
        CMTaskPriority GetCMTaskPriorityById(int CMTaskPriorityID);
        CMTaskPriority UpdateCMTaskPriority(CMTaskPriority cmtaskpriority);
        CMTaskPriority CreateCMTaskPriority(CMTaskPriority cmtaskpriority);
    }
```

CMTaskPriorityController.cs

```
[ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class CMTaskPriorityController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly ICMTaskPriorityRepository _CMTaskPriorityRepository;

        public CMTaskPriorityController(ICMTaskPriorityRepository CMTaskPriorityRepository)
        {
            _CMTaskPriorityRepository = CMTaskPriorityRepository;
        }


        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult GetCMTaskPriority()
        {
            return Ok(_CMTaskPriorityRepository.GetAllCMTaskPriority());
        }



        [HttpGet("{TaskPriorityID}")]
        public IActionResult GetTaskPriorityByID(int id)
        {
            return Ok(_CMTaskPriorityRepository.GetCMTaskPriorityById(id));
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult CreateCMTaskPriority([FromBody] CMTaskPriority cmtaskpriority)
        {
            if (cmtaskpriority == null)
                return BadRequest();

            if (cmtaskpriority.PriorityLevel == string.Empty || cmtaskpriority.PriorityLevel == string.Empty)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("Priority/Level", "The priority level shouldn't be empty");
            }

            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                return BadRequest(ModelState);

            var createdCMTaskPriority = _CMTaskPriorityRepository.CreateCMTaskPriority(cmtaskpriority);

            return Created("cmtaskpriority", createdCMTaskPriority);
        }

        [HttpPut]
        public IActionResult UpdateCMTaskPriority([FromBody] CMTaskPriority cmtaskpriority)
        {
            if (cmtaskpriority == null)
                return BadRequest();

            if (cmtaskpriority.PriorityLevel == string.Empty || cmtaskpriority.PriorityLevel == string.Empty)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("Priority/Level", "The priority level shouldn't be empty");
            }

            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                return BadRequest(ModelState);

            var CMTaskPriorityToUpdate = _CMTaskPriorityRepository.GetCMTaskPriorityById(cmtaskpriority.TaskPriorityID);

            if (CMTaskPriorityToUpdate == null)
                return NotFound();

            _CMTaskPriorityRepository.UpdateCMTaskPriority(cmtaskpriority);

            return NoContent(); //success

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please, start your question with "Apologies if this is something too complex", not "Apologies if this is something simple" ;}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your interface contains this:

```
IEnumerable<CMTaskPriority> GetAllCMTaskPriority();
```

But your class has this:

```
public IEnumerable<CMTaskPriority> GetAllCMTaskPrioritys()
```

Note the extra "s" on the end of your class's method name. This causes the compiler not to recognize this method as the implementation of the interface's defined method. Removing the "s" on the end of "GetAllCMTaskPrioritys" should fix your immediate issue.

Comment: Thank you so much! this has been driving me crazy and just could not see it.